# How to make an old school "much less/greater" (<< and >>) symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How can the *old school* "much less (or greater)" – `<<` and `>>` – symbol:

[image]

be made? I haven't succeeded with http://detexify.kirelabs.org.

Note I don't want the common `\ll` & `\gg` symbols.

Comment: For reference, here is the comprehensive symbol list: http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: `\Vee` and `\Wedge` are the vertical versions of what you're looking for...

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know about this symbol. Is it available in unicode? What's its unicode name/code?

Comment: never seen that symbol. You usually write `<<` like the font here, but with the second tip slightly closer, but the ending of the two `<` are not aligned like in your image.

Comment: @Bakuriu See, e.g., [here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1999ApJ...512..288T) (sect. 2.2.2, for instance). It's from 20 years ago, that's why I called it _old school_.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `mathabx` package provides this glyph as `\lll` (and correspondingly `\ggg`). However, `mathabx` changes a *lot* of symbols. If you want only these two you may easily adapt the code from [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14388/82917)

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lt}{3}{matha}{"CE}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gt}{3}{matha}{"CF}

\begin{document}

$a \ll b \Lt c \Gt d \gg e$

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** I was reminded in comments that `\lll` and `\ggg` are defined also in `amssymb` (and other math font packages) to do something else. The names `\Lt`, `\Gt` (from `stix`. `unicode-math` & others) avoid such clashes.

The [nice answer by Davislor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430564/82917) also shows how to import these symbols from the `stix` fonts, though in that case I'd switch fonts completely. In a Computer Modern setting I find the `mathabx` symbols more suitable.

Comment: Unfortunately, other packages, including `unicode-math`, declare `\lll` to mean ⋘. triple less than, and `\ggg` to mean ⋙, triple greater than.

Comment: @Davislor That's just a name. Call them `\varll`/`\vargg` and the clash is gone.

Comment: With your sample, that’s possible. I’d recommend `\Lt` and `\Gt` for compatibility with other packages. If you load `mathabx`, though, it will redefine the `\lll` and `\ggg` from `amssymb` to mean something different. It’s a design flaw in the package.

Comment: @Davislor True. I'll change the names.

Answer (score 15):

If you use `stix`, here is a version that creates a `newcommand` and rotates the symbols to give what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stix}
\newcommand{\lWedge}{\mathbin{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\Wedge$}}}
\newcommand{\gWedge}{\mathbin{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\Wedge$}}}
\begin{document}

$\lWedge$
$\gWedge$
$\Wedge$
$\Vee$

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT:
`Lt` and `Gt` exist, so no need to rotate.

Comment: I'd use `\mathrel` rather than `\mathbin`.

Comment: Yep I just saw that. Well, this was fun anyway.

Comment: Are there any drawbacks of the `stix`? Overridden definitions or so?

Comment: @corey979 `stix` will change _all_ fonts. The `stix` fonts (which by default replace also text fonts) are like Times. If you are writing in Computer Modern and only use those two symbols I believe the `mathabx` versions look better. One can import the two symbols from `stix` but they don't look good with CM.

Comment: @Davislor Yes, it already says that in my answer.

Answer (score 12):

These characters are in Unicode, ⪡ as U+2AA1 and ⪢ as U+2AA2. They have the macro names `\Lt` and `\Gt` in `unicode-math` ([*q.v.* pages 74–75](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf)), the `stix` package ([p. 16](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/stix/doc/stix.pdf)), the `stix2` package ([p.16](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/stix2-type1/stix2.pdf)) , and at least one other.

The OpenType fonts XITS Math, Stix Two Math, Asana Math, GFS Neohellenic Math and Cambria Math all contain the glyphs, and it is possible in `unicode-math` to fill in only those characters with a command such as:

```
\setmathfont[range={`⪡,`⪢}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Asana Math}
```

A code sample that works with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
\( \delta \Lt h \Gt \epsilon \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Stix Two Math]

And one that works with any LaTeX engine:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}
\( \delta \Lt h \Gt \epsilon \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Stix]

Should you be forced to use a legacy NFSS font package that does not contain these symbols, you might be able to load `\usepackage{stix}` before the other font packages. But, when another package is incompatible (perhaps because you run out of LaTeX math alphabets) and you need to declare them with `\DeclareMathSymbol`, you can do it with a bit of reverse-engineering. The following template declares `\Lt` and `\Gt` for use with `newtxmath`:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixsymbb}{LS1}{stixbb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lt}{\mathrel}{stixsymbb}{"F1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gt}{\mathrel}{stixsymbb}{"F2}

\begin{document}
\( \delta \Lt h \Gt \epsilon \)
\end{document}
```

[image: newtxmath plus stix]

Note that this is a contrived example, and the practical code you would use to get `newtx` fonts plus all symbols in `stix` is in fact:

```
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
```

You can additionally insert the following lines to be able to use the UTF-8 characters directly within your document, if you are not using `unicode-math` (which does that out of the box):

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{⪡}{\ensuremath{\Lt}}
\newunicodechar{⪢}{\ensuremath{\Gt}}
```

For completeness: the `boisik` package also defines `\Lt` and `\Gt`, but (as of 2018) is only available as a bitmap font.  It is therefore probably not an acceptable option.

As pointed out in another answer, `mathabx` contains similar glyphs, but declares them as `\lll` and `\ggg`.  **This is a serious design flaw** and will cause incorrect output when migrating to a different stylesheet. In the standard AMS fonts, `unicode-math` and several other common packages, `\lll` is ⋘. triple less than, and `\ggg` is ⋙, triple greater than.

I would recommend `unicode-math` as the first option and `stix` as the second.  If you want to load the glyphs from `mathabx`, I would use campa’s answer, revised to change the names to the more standard `\Lt` and `\Gt`.

Answer (score -1):

Another hacky way (with no font imports) is to use negative thin space characters `\!`:

```latex
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\newcommand{\mll}{<\!\!\!<} % change the number of \! characters to move closer/farther

\begin{document}
\( \delta \mll h \ll \epsilon \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) This provides something similar to `\ll`, which is exactly what the OP does *not* want.

Comment: Ha! You're right, I misread the question and thought that they were asking it the other way around.